# Why does my FTP upload fail intermittently?

Tags: c#, ssis, ftp

I have a bit of C# code (part of a scheduled SSIS job) that uploads a file an FTP.  The file is already present on the FTP site, so the job is just overwriting it with a newer version.

Most of the time it works great, but every few weeks it will begin to fail.  The most recent time this has happened, I found that the initial error is "427 Aborted, file write error".  Other times I have received "451, Local error in processing".  After the initial failure, every subsequent time the job tries to run it returns "550 File Unavailable".  When I open the site using Filezilla after getting this error, I find that my target file is there but empty.  If I delete the empty file using Filezilla, the job will begin working again.

I have altered my code to first delete the file in question, then upload the new one in hopes that will serve as a workaround.  I have been unable to reproduce this error, so time will tell if the workaround helps.

That said, I would like to figure out the root cause.  I've been able to find very little info on the 427 error.  Anyone have any idea how to avoid it or an idea for a better workaround?

Note: the FTP server is a proprietary thing, and I don't have much control over it other than username, password, & port.

My code is below (edited for brevity)...

```
private void CreateFile(FtpWebRequest request, FtpWebResponse response, string ipAddress, Int16 port, string folderName, string username, string password)
{
    string filename = "myfile.csv";
    request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("ftp://{0}:{1}/{2}/{3}", ipAddress, port, folderName, filename));
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.UsePassive = false;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
    request.GetResponse();

    request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("ftp://{0}:{1}/{2}/{3}", ipAddress, port, folderName, filename));
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.UsePassive = false;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        DataTable myList = new DataTable();
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
        da.Fill(myList, Dts.Variables["MyList"].Value);

        foreach (DataRow row in myList.Rows)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(row["col1"]);
        }
        sw.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the issue is not related to DNS. Are you using a FQDN or the IP?

Comment: Have you tried coding this using another library just to see if you experience the same issues? Usually intermitent problems like this sound like a server. I have been down this road before and most times it was not the client code. Perhaps you should just build some retry logic into your code.

Comment: I have not yet tried another library.  I have tried building in some retry logic, but it would keep failing until I went in & deleted the file.  It seems to leave the file in some sort of intermediate state.  You are probably correct, I think the server may be the issue; I'm just trying to find the best workaround.

Comment: Could you copy the file over with a different name and once transmission is complete delete the original file then rename your new file to the old one? I know there are limitations around certain libraries but it should be doable.

Comment: haha, we must think alike.  I actually tried almost exactly that.  I would create the file with a different name, and then rename it which would overwrite the old.  The way I tried did not help, but deleting the old file first might.

Comment: FTP servers are a funny thing. I guess you could always keep copies as back up with the sending process so that you have back up in case deleting the file causes an issue.